# How to perform non-orthogonal planned contrasts (and a-priori power-analysis for this)?

Tags: statistical-power, contrasts, planned-comparisons-test

I have four treatment groups (A, B, C, D) and measure three dependent variables (X, Y, Z).
My hypotheses are that each dependent variable is strongest in one of the treatment groups, compared to all others. I plan to test this using planned comparisons. So, for example, the contrast weights could be 3 -1 -1 -1 for X, -1 3 -1 -1 for Y and -1 -1 3 -1 for Z.

I found one article which did a similar analysis, https://doi.org/10.1177/0146167207309193.
They go about it as follows:

1. They defined focal contrasts for each dependent variable as I described above.

> For each of the three theoretical predictions, a contrast was
> created that described the hypothesized rank order of means
> regarding one group-based emotion (A > B = C = D). This is represented in the focal contrast with the coefficients 3-1-1-1.

2. To check whether there is systematic variance other than that predicted, orthogonal contrasts were computed in addition to the focal contrast.

> Orthogonal contrasts are important because they reveal whether there
> is residual variance that is not explained by the focal contrast. If
> the hypothesis represented in the focal contrast is correct, the
> focal contrast should be significant, and ideally, the orthogonal
> contrast should not be significant. Given that there were four exper
> imental conditions, we had 2 df to compute two orthogo nal contrasts
> (001-1 and 0-211).

3. For each contrast, they added the other two dependent variables as covariates in the contrast analyses.

> To account for the intercorrelations between the emotions, and thus
> general emotionality, we included the nonfocal emotions as covariates
> in the contrast analyses

This leaves a few questions open.

1. These comparisons are, of course, not orthogonal, so i**s this analytic approach at all appropriate**?
2. If it is, is **alpha-level correction** necessary? Would simple Bonferroni-correction be sufficient?
3. Is it appropriate to include the **nonfocal dependent variables as covariates**?
4. How would you do an **a-priori power analysis** for this type of analysis?

Bonus question: Do you have any recommendations for the appropriate way/library to do this analysis in R?

I am grateful for any help or literature recommendations on this!